# while using signalr getting error in connection build

Tags: react-native

link:-https://github.com/jonathanzufi/SignalR-ReactNativeClient
using this library and getting error in building connection

error: [2021-10-21T11:37:44.853Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
[Thu Oct 21 2021 17:07:43.711]  LOG      [2021-10-21T11:37:44.854Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'.
[Thu Oct 21 2021 17:07:43.712]  LOG      [2021-10-21T11:37:44.855Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: https://signalrdemo.com/chatHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1.
[Thu Oct 21 2021 17:07:43.714]  LOG      {"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null} connect
[Thu Oct 21 2021 17:07:43.721]  WARN     [2021-10-21T11:37:44.887Z] Warning: Error from HTTP request. 0: undefined.
[Thu Oct 21 2021 17:07:43.772]  LOG      Global error handler
[Thu Oct 21 2021 17:07:43.818]  LOG      Global error handler
[Thu Oct 21 2021 17:07:43.820]  LOG      [2021-10-21T11:37:44.946Z] Debug: HubConnection failed to start successfully because of error 'Error'.
[Thu Oct 21 2021 17:07:43.820]  LOG      [Error] err::::::::::::::
[Thu Oct 21 2021 17:07:43.821]  LOG      Error starting the connection: Error

technology used :-react-native

Comment: Did you got any solution ?